# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied C#

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures

I have initialise properly everything but whenever I run my program, it crashes, giving me that error. I'm trying to check in the database if the username exist using stored procedure. Here's my code:

```
public bool checkUsername()
    {
        bool exist = false;
        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsername", myCon))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows == true)
                    {
                        exist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            myCon.Close();
        }
        return exist;
    }
```

Here's my Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spCheckUsername
@user nvarchar(50)
AS
    SELECT * FROM tblUserAccount, tblUserInfo
    WHERE tblUserAccount.username = @user AND tblUserInfo.username = @user

RETURN 0
```

Comment: I already did it, using Parameters.Add. is that what you mean?

Comment: That is incorrect Sani, because he is setting ComandType to Storedprocedure. ADO.NET does that for you.

Comment: Only thing other than my answer I can think of is if @user's value is not a string.

Comment: @psibernetic the value of \n@user is nvarchar(50) and it's value in my class is string

Comment: does this proc execute in SQL Server Management Studio with one parameter? If so, I recommend using SQL Profiler to see what is being sent from the application.

Comment: Its not answer but by good practices please check here for proc naming https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx but dont know particularly about sp but sureyl sp_ is a no, and also dr.HasRows == true can be eliminated, if its mean to be production level code :-)